# Codeeval Challenge not returning correct output. (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I started doing the challenges in codeeval and i'm stuck at an easy challenge called "word to digit"

This is the challenge description:

> Having a string representation of a set of numbers you need to print
>   this numbers.
>        All numbers are separated by semicolon. There are up to 20 numbers in one line. The numbers are "zero" to "nine"

input sample:

> zero;two;five;seven;eight;four
>
> three;seven;eight;nine;two

output sample:

> 025784
>
> 37892

I have tested my code and it works, but in codeeval the output is always missing the last number from each line of words in the input file.

This is my code:

```
import sys

def WordConverter(x):
    test=str()
    if (x=="zero"):
        test="0"
    elif (x=="one"):
        test="1"
    elif (x=="two"):
        test="2"
    elif (x=="three"):
        test="3"
    elif (x=="four"):
        test="4"
    elif (x=="five"):
        test="5"
    elif (x=="six"):
        test="6"
    elif (x=="seven"):
        test="7"
    elif (x=="eight"):
        test="8"
    elif (x=="nine"):
        test="9"
    return (test)

t=str()
string=str()
test_cases=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
for line in test_cases:
    string=line.split(";")
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        t+=WordConverter(string[i])
    print (t)
    t=str()
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a Codeeval bug?

Comment: its just to erase it and let it know its a string variable to repeat the loop with the t variable blank again.

Comment: `t = ""` will do that, `string` also a builtin module name, best not to shadow the name. You don't need parens around  your `if/elif` statements either.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I submitted it with python 3, and you need ()

Comment: you don't. For `print` you do as in python 3 it is a function as opposed to a statement in python 2 but you don't need parens for statements.

Comment: Consider using a dictionary instead of a bunch of elifs. Define a dictionary that maps word representations of numbers to numeral representations. Then your function can be reduced to `def word_converter(s): return numbers[s]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the newline char from the input. Replace:

```
string=line.split(";")
```

With

```
string=line.strip().split(";")
```

However, using `string` as the variable name is not a good decision...

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `string` as a variable name, actually. Most of the stuff in the `string` module is now part of the `str` type anyway, or else is of very limited use.

Comment: @kindall, what happens if the OP imports string sometime then uses string as a variable name?

Comment: changed variable name also

Comment: There are a lot of Python modules; you can't rule then all out. If you import `string`, yeah, you'd have problems,  but I wouldn't worry about it until you actually need something from that module, which I would consider rare.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over the lines of a file with `for line in test_cases:`, each value of `line` will include the newline at the end of the line (if any).  This results in the last element of `string` having a newline at the end, and so this value won't compare equal to anything in `WordConverter`, causing an empty string to be returned.  You need to remove the newline from the string at some point.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to as the newline?

Comment: @FutoFarai: The character(s) that signal(s) the end of a line (on *nix) or separate two lines (on Windows): `'\n'` on *nix, `'\r\n'` on Windows, or `'\r'` on Mac OS Classic.

Comment: ooh yeah yeah sorry, forgot about that.